# pfSense router gives DNS rebinding warning when accessing subdomains

Tags: domain-name-system, subdomain, pfsense

I have just set up a router running pfSense on our network and forwarded the appropriate ports. I have a small web server running in my network, and a domain name pointing to our (WAN) IP. When accessing that domain name, everything works fine. However, when accessing a subdomain of the domain name, pfSense will give a DNS rebinding warning. This did not happen back when I used a DD-WRT router. What is the proper way to fix this? The DNS records for the subdomain also point to the same address (I use a virtual server to differentiate the subdomains.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [once VPNed into pfSense, unable to hit the public URLs of my websites - they are routed to the pfSense box](http://serverfault.com/questions/235083/once-vpned-into-pfsense-unable-to-hit-the-public-urls-of-my-websites-they-are)

Comment: For information, if you have a DynDNS domain or a domain name on a static public IP, just add in System -> Advance in the field "alternate hostnames" the name of your DynDNS domain or domain name and it works like a charm without pure NAT or split DNS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is due to the fact that PF functions can't reflect in and out the same interface, it has to pass "through" the router so it redirects you to the warning. You can setup a .local domain or you can setup Split DNS in PFsense. Instructions for split DNS are in this PFsense [KB](http://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/Why_can%27t_I_access_forwarded_ports_on_my_WAN_IP_from_my_LAN/OPTx_networks?) article. I suggest split DNS to fix this.

Comment: Jacob, I'm sure you know that it's generally discouraged from